# Crystal Report: SQL Subquery Issue with 'null' Results

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

When I run the following SQL query in SMS, I correctly get "null" values in the second document_desc column (from patient_documents_1). This shows me that the patient documents that exist for a certain patient do not include the required bh_pharm document. Perfect!

```
SELECT
patients.last_name, patients.first_name, 
patient_documents.document_description,
patient_documents_1.document_description
FROM patients
INNER JOIN patient_documents ON patients.pat_id = patient_documents.pat_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    select patient_documents.pat_id, patient_documents.document_description
    from patient_documents where patient_documents.document_description = 'bh_pharm' )
    as patient_documents_1 ON patients.pat_id = patient_documents_1.pat_id
WHERE
( patient_documents.timestamp >= {ts '2015-02-01 00:00:00'} AND patient_documents.timestamp < {ts '2015-03-01 00:00:00'} ) AND 
patient_documents_1.document_description is null
```

How can I do this in a Crystal Report?

Everything I try results in an empty report. Either that or I have to include every record and every document description. I only want the report to show me what patients are missing the "bh_pharm" document. Can Crystal Reports handle 'null' results from a subquery or subreport?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Which version of Crystal is this? Are you using a command?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work without the LEFT JOIN to the subquery?  Ie do you get results after taking out that join and all references to patient_documents_1?

If not, then make sure you are configuring crystal reports to query the SQL Server correctly.

Edit:
Does this work?  It might be the curly braces but I also did some gratuitous rewriting...

```
    WITH patient_documents_1 as
    (
        select patient_documents.pat_id
        from patient_documents 
where patient_documents.document_description = 'bh_pharm'
group by patient_documents.pat_id
    ),
    noBH as (
    SELECT
    patients.last_name, 
    patients.first_name, 
    patients.pat_id
    FROM patients
    LEFT OUTER JOIN patient_documents_1 on patients.pat_id = patient_documents_1.pat_id
    WHERE
    patient_documents_1.document_description is null 
    )
    Select 
    noBH.*,
    patient_documents.document_description
    from noBH
    INNER JOIN patient_documents ON noBH.pat_id = patient_documents.pat_id
    WHERE
    patient_documents.timestamp between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-28'
```

Oh yeah, are there patients who don't have the bh_pharm document but do have timestamps in feb 2015?

Comment: SQL query works just fine no matter how I break it down.

Basically what I am trying to do is this: (a silly example)

If I have books in my library, only tell me the list of books if none of those books are "Treasure Island". If "Treasure Island" is one of the books, I don't want a list of the books.

Any working example you give me for Crystal Reports would help me get on track.

Comment: Thanks, bf2020, that helped a lot. Not completely what I need to accomplish with this report, but you answered my question and it gets me back on track. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey Darryl Grimes, can you upvote or mark as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Open the crystal report then there instead of selecting the tables select command and copy the same query there.

Now go design and generate the report.

Comment: I've tried that as well. I've also tried a subreport. I explained my situation in an example above, responding to bf2020's answer.

Comment: A formula I tried using select expert on a subreport that obviously failed was ... and 'bh_pharm' is not in [ {patient_documents.document_description} ] ... is there a way to dynamically create a list or array of existing document_descriptions within this formula?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a new report.

The only table you need to add to your report is the `patients` table. (If you alias it then make sure to change it in the query below.)

Add a SQL Expression to return the count. It will evaluate to zero when no documents with the right description are found. Copy everything below including the parentheses. Call it something like `DocumentCount`.

```
(
select count(*)
    from patient_documents as pd
where
    pd.document_description = 'bh_pharm'
    and pd.pat_id = patients.pat_id  /* alias on "patients" must match */
)
```

Add a filter to the record select formula to limit it to the ones you want to display.

```
{%DocumentCount} = 0
```